# How to cause delay that work synchronic with the code -javascript

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){

  code

  setTimeout

  code

}
```

I want to prevent from the loop to proceed until timeout is finish ,any idea??

Comment: I believe you're looking for the facsimile of a [javascript `sleep()`](http://www.devcheater.com/).

Comment: ... and you'll eventually find that, in the context of a web browser, there's really no such thing as "sleep()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got Function.prototype.bind() available:

```
function operation() {
  if (!this) return;
  // do something
  setTimeout(operation.bind(--this), 1000);
}
setTimeout(operation.bind(10), 1000);
```

Comment: Can't say I'm a fan of using the number as the truthy evaluation to stop what amounts to a decrement loop. Why not be explicit about it and just test for 0 directly (this === 0)?  Makes more clear what the code is doing, IMHO.

Comment: Well, I'm a C programmer at heart :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;

nextMove( );

function nextMove( ) {

    i++;

    if( i != 10 ) setTimeout(nextMove,3000);

}
```

Comment: There's no reason to pass a string to "setTimeout()" like that - much better to just pass the name of the function, "nextMove".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, changed the post.. Is there a way to pass variables if you do it like this?

Comment: if you are wanting to pass variables, you use wrap it in an anonymous function - setTimeout(function(){ nextMove(10); }, 1000);

Comment: well yes, if you have [".bind()"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) available, or if you add a wrapper anonymous function. Also, when you deal strictly with function references, you can leverage closures, which often makes passing parameters unnecessary.

Comment: @Matt, @Pointy ok, thats clear. I'll have a look at the bind() docs sometime. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This repeats 10 times:

```
var j = 10;

setTimeout(someFunction, 1000);

function someFunction()
{
    if (j > 0)
        setTimeout(someFunction, 1000);
    j = j - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no way to delay the execution of a block of code that follows an instruction that is being executed.

The only thing you can do is to wrap the code that need to be delayed around a function and use set time out just like the previous comments suggest.